# Subclassing Global and overriding Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, global-asax, vs-web-application-project

I have a couple of web applications whose source code is missing. The project is compiled to a dll and is hosted on a IIS.

I have couple of questions to make.

- What is the best way to recreate the
  project from the dll file??
- We are planning to change the
  database server, and the database
  connection strings are specified in
  the Global.asax ( `I mean the public
  class Global : HttpApplication` ). Is
  there a way I can subclass this
  Global and override the connection
  strings? If yes, how can I make the
  IIS refer to the new dll

Thank you all for any suggestions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first part, use decompiler tools such as [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com)/[ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)/[dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to convert IL code from DLL to higher level language such as C#. However, tools cannot get back comments, local variable names and project structure. You need to manually organize the code into files and project structures. From aspx files, you have to figure out the code-behind classes and then link up the source of the class into a correct named code-behind file - for example, if default.aspx says that it *inherits* from `MyApp.Default` then create file default.aspx.xs and put the source code for the class into that.

For second part, you can create a new class derived from `Global` and modify Global.asax to use that class - you need to put the assembly containing new class in bin folder and overwrite `inherits` clause in asax file to point to the type name of new class. You anyway need to inspect the code of your current Global class (using tools sighted above) to see if you can override connection strings by sub-classing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably the best tool available to reverse engineer a dll into code is [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1). Unfortunately, the latest version is no longer free, but it is worth the money.
2. I am not sure exactly if this still applies if you can already reverse engineer your source code. However, I would recommend moving your connection strings outside of your project into web.config as a best practice. This way you can make the change in the future without changing any code.